# How can I let my code rearrange the list to put all even numbers at the front and odd numbers at the back?

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to let my code return the list with all even numbers at the front and the odd numbers being appended at the end of the list. Here is my code so far...

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,5]
def evenorodd(s):
    s = list(s)
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i]%2 != 0:
            s.append(i)
    return s
print(evenorodd(s = [1,2,3,4,5,5]))
```

and this is the output that I get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0, 2, 4]
```

but I want my output to be

```
[0,2,2,4,4,1,3,5,5]
```

What changes should I make

**Order doesn't matter btw.. it's just that all even numbers must come before odd ones**

Comment: your initial list only had 6 numbers. Why should your desired output have more numbers?

Comment: You could do a sort-of [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: Surely the expected result of "put all even numbers at the front and odd numbers at the back?" is `[2,4,1,3,5,5]`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create two new lists in your function, one for even and one for odd numbers. Append each number to the correct list inside your loop. Once you're finished concatenate the lists together and return.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` to create your custom sort method for a list

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,5,0,2]
s = sorted(s, key=lambda x: not x%2)
>>> [1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4, 0, 2]
```

and if you want to sort the even number with themselves and the odd numbers too

```
s = [1,2,3,4,5,5,0,2]
s.sort()
s = sorted(s, key=lambda x: not x%2)
>>> [1, 3, 5, 5, 0, 2, 2, 4]
```

Comment: I know `sort` is stable, but you could even do it all in one pass `sorted(s, key=lambda x: (not x%2, x))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can append to two lists and concatenate them:

```
def evenorodd(s):
    evens = []
    odds = []
    for num in s:
        if num%2 == 0:
            evens.append(num)
        else:
            odds.append(num)
    return evens + odds
```